# Can't see Diagnostics Tools in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Hello, after clean installation of Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise I can't see Diagnostic Tools.

[image: screenshot]

In settings I've enabled Diagnostic Tools. I tried to reset layout but still same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe it's too late, but anyway, enable the window of Diagnostic Tool under: 
Debug -> Windows -> Show Diagnostic Tools or use shortcut **Ctrl+Alt+F2**.
  Here is how it looks like:

[image: Here is how it looks like:]